# uitableviewcell exception error: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c15b730'

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am receiving a chat message from signalR server. now i want to display the chat message in tableview..so i am writing like this.. my response is like this “”  "(\n\"(alex" Hi)”)..”alex” is user name and “hi” is text message.i want to display these two items in tableview. but my response is having special characters.so i am writing my code like this.

```
-(void)messagesReceived:(id)data
{
    if(data)   
    {
        NSArray *arrCount;
        NSArray *arr=(NSArray *)data;
        arrCount=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr, nil];
        NSString *str1=[arrCount description];
        NSArray* strArray = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
        NSString* userName = [strArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"user Name  is :%@",userName);
        NSArray *arrName=[userName componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"arr is:%@",arrName);
        NSString *messageText=[strArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"message array is:%@",messageText);
        messageText=[messageText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")\"\n)" withString:@""];
        messageText=[messageText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSArray *arr1=[messageText componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"array value is:%@",arr1);
        itemsDataArr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:arr1, nil];
        NSLog(@"Items array is:%@",itemsDataArr); 
        [_ChattblView reloadData];
    }
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [itemsDataArr count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_ChattblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
     }
     cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     if (itemsDataArr.count>0) {
          cell.textLabel.text=[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      }
      return cell;
  }
```

but i got exception this line of code..

```
cell.textLabel.text=[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the exception is like this

> -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c15b730”
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c15b730'

Comment: Somehow you are perform `isEqualToString` operation with an Array. Because it expects the parameter to be a string, therefore you get a crash. Search your code for the place where you are using `isEqualToString` method and see the type of parameters in debugging mode

Comment: Can you add a backtrace for this exception?

Comment: `[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is a `NSArray`, not a `NSString` since you do `itemsDataArr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:arr1, nil];`.

Comment: @Larme thanks for your response. can you give me any code.. how to fix my issue.. plz

Comment: Your code is really messy, especially for `messagesReceived:`. Try `cell.textLabel.text = [[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:??]`

Comment: @satya "gimme-teh-codez" is not going to help you. The problem is within your existing code. Find it and make sure that the object on which you are calling the method `isEqualToString` is a String. You can use `[exampleObject isKindOfClass:[NSString Class]]` for that.

Comment: @Larme thanks for response  ..can i write like this? ?cell.textLabel.text=[[itemsUserNameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: @Larme if i write the above like that i got exception -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: The new error is telling you that you only have one item in your array and that item is at index 0, not 1.

Comment: @PhillipMills then how to change my code.. plz give me idea